# Populating .Xauthority file when DISPLAY and HOST variables are non-existent

Tags: debian, openbox, xinit, xauth

I just installed the new Debian 10 Buster and I am not satisfied. I installed it without any desktop. Only `basic system utilities`  were installed during the initial install.

After reboot I signed in with a `root` user and added i386 architecture support using `dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Then I modified the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file where I added `contrib non-free` at the end of every line and added one more line for a `buster-backports` repository. I saved the file and updated apt.

Then I instelled `sudo` using `apt install sudo` and modifying the `/etc/sudoers` file so that my user ziga's rights are defined with a line `ziga ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. Then I signed out and signed back in using my user `ziga`.

I installed some packages `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core xinit openbox`, I created the `~/.xinitrc` file with a line `exec openbox-session` and I ran `startx`.

Openbox never came up. The first time I used `startx` I saw a warning saying something like:

> *".Xauthority file not found"*

and then everything hangs until after some time it fails and prints:

> *"xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permited)"*

The 1st message never came up again after retryig `startx` while 2nd message did come up after a while (each time), so `~.Xauthority` was probably created, but Openbox still didn't start. This is why I checked the `xauth list` command and it printed nothing. This means I have to add a line to it! Well I tried by using `xauth` ([forum](https://superuser.com/questions/806637/xauth-not-creating-xauthority-file)) like this:

```
# For X11 over SSH 
xauth generate :0 . trusted 

# Generate my own key, xauth requires 128 bit hex encoding
xauth add ${HOST}:0 . $(xxd -l 16 -p /dev/urandom)
```

But this failed, because there is no variable `DISPLAY` and no variable `HOST` defined (checked with `printenv`). Also 1st command returns `unable to open display ":0"`. Well I am on a laptop and display is clearly attached...

So does anyone have any suggestions. I want to use Openbox... =)

Comment: I suspect you either need to set up `logind` and `libpam-systemd`, or install `xserver-xorg-legacy` and configure that. See `/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-core/NEWS.Debian.gz` for details and pointers.

Comment: When I read the `.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` There is a lot of lines at the end saying something like `systemd-logind: got pause for 14:52` where time differs a bit. So you might be right. But `xserver-xorg-legacy` was installed as a dependancy with package `xserver-xorg-core` so it is installed.

Comment: I tried executing `startx` as a `root` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: you should ignore that message about .Xauthority; xauth will create it automatically. That's not the cause of the hang. It's because you're trying run Xorg as a non-root user (the iopl error message tells it all). I suggest you install a proper display manager (even xdm is fine) that will be started as a service, and forget about and **remove** all that sudo crap (`apt-get remove --purge sudo` should do)

Comment: @UncleBilly Why would I delete remove sudo? I don't understand that. Please write an answer and explain a bit.

Comment: Yours is an XY question. You're assuming that it's because of that innocent xauth warning that you're not able  to run X11, and that starting X11 via sudo + xinit is the way to go. Both assumptions are false. You should start X11 via a display manager, as it works by default in most distros.

Comment: As to sudo, sudo is ONLY useful for running commands copy-pasted from forums without understanding what they're doing. You decide whether that's a smart thing to do.

Comment: @Uncle Billy I've done this up untill now. I've done it in on Arch Linux, Arch Linux ARM, Debian 8, Debian 9 and now I am trying to do it in Debian 10 which is somehow screwed up and won't start X. Even Arch wiki says this is how it is supposed to be done (read Arch Wiki Openbox). Some of us don't like "fancy" display managers... And why would you delete sudo? Isn't it the only option to run applications in a priviliged way for normal users?